# Firebase Phone Number Verification on GoLang Admin SDK

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I have a simple use case,

I want to provide an endpoint to my clients `/users/register` where they capture the phone number and send it to the endpoint.

I then initiate a Phone Number Validation Process on the Admin End and send back a response to the client to enter the verification code sent to them via `/users/validate`. When they've received the verification code, they will now send it back through another endpoint `/users/verify_code`. Upon confirmation I can now go ahead and create a `CustomToken` and finally send back the custom token to the client for final signIn.

Is there a way to achieve this on the Go Admin Sdk?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase Admin SDKs have no way to trigger sending of verification text messages, or verification emails. Such actions can only be triggered from within the client-side SDKs.

If you'd like to request that this functionality be added to the Firebase Admin SDK for Go, you can [file a bug report or feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).